# Clear All Existing Entries In DynamoDB Table In AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

My goal is to take daily snapshots of an RDS table and put it in a DynamoDB table. The table should only contain data from a single day.

For this have a Data Pipeline set up to query a RDS table and publish the results into S3 in CSV format.

Then a HiveActivity imports this CSV into a DynamoDB table by creating external tables for the file and an existing DynamoDB table.

This works great, but older entries from the previous day still exist in the DynamoDB table. I want to do this within Data Pipeline if at all possible. I need to:

1) Find a way to clear the DynamoDB table, or at least drop/recreate it, or
2) Include an extra column of the snapshot date and find a way to clear out all older entries.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamoDb **[Time to Live](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html)(TTL)** which allows you to set an expiration time after which items are auto deleted from the DynamoDb table. TTL is very useful for cases where data loses it's relevance after a specific time period and in your case it can be start time of next day.